# python multiprocessing.pool application

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multiprocessing

following (simplified) code applies an interpolation function on the multiprocessing module:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
...
if __name__=="__main__":
    p=Pool(4)
    lndi = LinearNDInterpolator(points, valuesA)
    valuesB = list(np.split(valuesA, 4))
    ret = p.map(lndi.__call__, valuesB)
```

when i run the .py, python freezes, if the last line is run separately everything works fine and i get the speed-up that i hoped for.
anyone knows how to fix the code to have it work automatically?

thanks in advance

edit: github issue was opened -> https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3367

Comment: i was able to fix the problem by avoiding the spyder environment. running my script from the command line or ipython directly worked properly. Must be some error in the IDE.